# get any string between last two slash or other last two same character with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

how to get any string between last two slash or other last two same character in javascript?

**use regex not split**   there's several similar question in so but I only can find answer is use split ...

my regex pattern in below, it not match do I miss something?

I was hoping the result is something like this, how to make it?

```
['s', index: .., input: ...]
```

regex

```
var str = '/a/b/c/s/';
var regexPattern = /([^/]*)\/$/;
str = regexPattern.exec(str);
console.log(str); // ["s/", "s"]
if (str == 's') {
   console.log(true)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30bjt5ew/

Comment: thanks for reply but point is the regex not match, otherwise will return something like this `['s', index: .....]`  than `str == 's'` will be work

Comment: no I run this on server side, and I tried yours, same result

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/30bjt5ew/1/ with `if (str[1] == 's') {`. I get `true` in  Chrome.

Comment: You have capture groups, and `exec` returns matches, not strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that same as my result if match it should be return like this `['s', index: .....]`

Comment: @KennethK.  I don't get it, how should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using non-greedy quantifiers?
Your regex could by like `var regexPattern = /.*\/(.+?)\/$/;`

Comment: Not changing any of the original jsfiddle I get `["s/", "s", index: 7, input: "/a/b/c/s/"]`

Comment: @fernandosavio it output `["/a/b/c/s/", "s"]`

Comment: if you want that the full match will be only `s` you may use `/([^/]*)(?=\/$)/` or without a select group: `/[^/]*(?=\/$)/`

Comment: @sdexp that's weird....  http://imgur.com/a/QaN0Y

Comment: Check [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). It says `The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured. `. So, the regex I wrote returns `/a/b/c/s/` as the match and `s` as the captured string which I thought you wanted.

Comment: You need to include, in the question itself, the inputs and outputs you're expecting.

Comment: Isn't as simple as `'/a/b/c/s/'.match(/\/(.)\/$/)`

Comment: @fernandosavio I only want `s`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I only want `s`

Comment: why get downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/[^/]*(?=\/$)/
```

it will output `["s", index: 7, input: "/a/b/c/s/"]` as you expected.

```
[^/]* # any char that is not /
(?=\/$) # Look foward for a / and the end of string
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30bjt5ew/2/)

Comment: This is a great solution, what I was going to suggest myself. I do have a suggestion I would have included in my own answer. "Between last two slashes" does not indicate that the last slash is actually at the end of the string. So you should add a quantifier to match any amount (0 or more) of non-slash characters after the last /. Based on the specifications presented, "a/b/   c" should match b, for example. With your regex as of now it would match nothing. (You might want to ask OP whether it is intended to force the / to be the last character. If so, then you're correct as is.)

Comment: @JosephMyers thanks for the suggestion! it' ok  now I can also test if null means not correct format string

Comment: `/[^/]*(?=\/[^/]*$)/` will match s if it the last `/` isn't in the end of the string as @Joseph Myers sugested. OP original regex was matching `/` at the end of the string, I suppose that it was what he wanted.